# c++ reference in recursion (reverse a stack)

Tags: c++, recursion

I am doing a very simple exercise on C++ recursion for reversing a stack recursively. The code is attached below. My problem is about whether I should use reference T& or simply T in my recursive call putToBottom(stack&, const T&).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void putToBottom(stack<T>& myStack, const T& topOne)
{
    if (myStack.empty()) 
    {
        myStack.push(topOne);
        return;
    }

//Should I use T& or T here???
    ***T temp = myStack.top();***
    myStack.pop();
    putToBottom(myStack, topOne);
    myStack.push(temp);
}

template <typename T>
void reverseStack(stack<T>& myStack)
{
    if (myStack.empty()) return;
    T& topOne = myStack.top();
    myStack.pop();
    reverseStack(myStack);
    putToBottom(myStack, topOne);
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> myStack;
    myStack.push(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(3);
    myStack.push(4);
    reverseStack(myStack);
    while (!myStack.empty())
    {
        cout << myStack.top() << "\n";
        myStack.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I write `T temp = myStack.top();`, I get the right answer (the stack is now 1 (top) -> 2 -> 3 -> 4). However, if I write `T& temp = myStack.top();` or `const T& temp = myStack.top();`, I get the wrong one (the stack becomes 4 (top) -> 4 -> 4 -> 4). Any ideas would help! Thank you!

Comment: If you use `T&` then it invokes undefined behavior because `myStack.pop()` invalidates the reference. Are you using C++11? If so then move semantics are probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `T& temp = myStack.top()`, then once you do `myStack.pop()`, `temp` becomes a dangling reference and it is undefined behavior to use it further.

If you are using C++11 then you probably want move semantics:

```
T temp = std::move(myStack.top());
myStack.pop();
putToBottom(myStack, topOne);
myStack.push(std::move(temp));
```

And similarly in `reverseStack`.

Although I have to note, this is a particularly inefficient way to reverse a stack. Better would be simply to pop everything off of the original stack while pushing it onto a second stack.

Comment: Thx for your reply! But sorry, I didn't quite get the point why I got a dangling reference... Even if the stack pops out the top item, the item is still alive in the scope. Then I think my temp variable should still be valid, right? Maybe I missed something important... Any ideas would help! Thx.

Comment: Just because it is in scope doesn't mean it's valid. You bind `myStack.top()` to the reference `temp` but that reference doesn't prolong the lifetime of the object. When you call `myStack.pop()`, the object's destructor `T::~T()` is called and the memory used to store it in the `std::stack` may get deallocated. Your reference `temp` could now be pointing to some unallocated memory, and using that reference is UB.

Comment: Oh... I didn't look into the implementation of pop()... Thank u sooooo much!